# npm how to change port on the server

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, server, port

I'm using npm (Node packege manager), with Angular2,
I'm trying to change the port of the server, but it
doesn't run, this is my bs-config.json:

```
 {
  "server": {
  "port": 8080
    "baseDir": "src",
    "routes": {
      "/node_modules": "node_modules"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: also you can try without changing permanently while running like this `ng serve --port 8080`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are two mistakes:
- You should declare the attribute 'port' with priority higher than the attribute 'server'
- You are missing the comma

Try this:

```
{
  // local port
  "port": 8080,
  "server": {
    "baseDir": "src",
    "routes": {
      "/node_modules": "node_modules"
    }
  }
}
```